# My variables are mixing values with each other ???? C++

Tags: c++, string, for-loop

I have two string variables that are mixing each others letters after a certain point and I have no idea why.

string dna1 and dna2 is read in from a .txt file like this:

```
string opfile1(string& dnafile, string& dnaseq1); // function dec 

string opfile2(string& dnafile, string& dnaseq2);

int main()
{
    string dna1;
    string dna2;
    string seq1;
    string seq2;

    order1 = openSecondFile(dna1, seq1);
    order2 = openThirdFile(dna2, seq2);

    //function calls ^

        string opfile1(string& dnafile, string& dnaseq1); // function dec 
    {
        string PName;
        string frag;
        ifstream in_s;

        in_s.open(dnafile.c_str());

        if(in_s.fail())     //if file does not exist a fail message will appear
        {
            cout << "Unable to open input file " << song1File << endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        getline(in_s, frag, '|');
        Name = frag.substr(1);

        in_s >> dnaseq1;

        in_s.clear();
        return Name;
    }
```

//func def.

The function `opfile2` is the exact same except wherever you see a '1', I replaced it with a '2' to match its variables.

Now when I print these out in my main function they appear like this:

```
cout << dnaseq1 << endl;
cout << dnaseq2 << endl;
```

Output:

```
FDFDAFDAF
DFDAFDATZY
```

Which is correct! Now, when I try to print them using a for loop this happens:

```
int columns = dnaseq1Size + 1;

for(int i = 0; i < columns; ++i)
{
    if(i == 0)
    {
        cout << setw(3) << "-" << " ";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << setw(3) << dnaseq2.at(i) << " ";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 9) >= this->size() (which is 9)
  -   D   F   D   A   F   D   A   F Aborted (core dumped)
```

(it starts printing the other notes)

I have no idea what's happening, can anyone help?

EDIT: I figured out the issue and fixed it. I think the issue had something to do with the fact I was using arrays and a "size" so I switched to a 2D vector and used .size instead and the issue fixed it self.

Comment: you don't show us anywhere how _song2Size_ is set.

Comment: Unfortunately noone else will have any idea what's happening either, and noone will be able to help until you [edit] your question so that it meets all requirements of a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help], where you can take a [tour] of stackoverflow.com and learn [ask] questions that are likely to get correct answers.

Comment: you don't show us the content of _openThirdFile_.

Comment: `std::out_of_range` means your `i` is too large. Why do you add 1 here: `int columns = song2Size + 1;` then execute `for(int i = 0; i < columns; ++i)` are there song2Size + 1 items or song2Size items?

Answer (score 0):

It's clear enough. Your string has size 9, (`FDFDAFDAF` for example) but you try and print `musicalnotes2.at(9)`. If your string has size 9 then only 0 to 8 are legal indexes

As said in the comments the suspicious part is when you write

```
int columns = song2Size + 1;
for(int i = 0; i < columns; ++i)
    ...
```

Why do you add one there? That seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like looks like your're trying to print out each char from the `musicalnotes` variables

one way to be able to do it is to wrap it in a function (easier to reuse)

```
void printNotes(const string &musicalNotes) {                              
    cout << setw(3) << "-" << " "; 
    for(int i = 0; i < musicalNotes.length(); ++i)
    {       
        cout << setw(3) << musicalNotes.at(i) << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}  

int main()
{
  //... code up until you wish to print it
  printNotes(musicalnotes1);
  printNotes(musicalnotes2);
  //... if you want something afterward
 return 0;
}
```

Here we replace the `int columns = song2Size + 1;` with the length of the string, and prior to writing anything from there we write out the `-`
Example output would be:

```
  -   F   D   F   D   A   F   D   A   F 
  -   D   F   D   A   F   D   A   T   Z   Y
```

I assume that `song2Size` would be equal to the `musicalnotes2.length()`, if that's the case you do write over the strings length and therefor you get your out of bounds error. If it contains 9 chars then it would be at index `0,1...7,8` not to `9`